# How to use array in PySMT?

Tags: python, arrays, smt, pysmt

I have a problem with PySMT. I'm new in the field and I have no idea how to use arrays.

I've understood that:

1) It's possible to declare an array as:

```
a = Symbol("a", ArrayType(INT, INT))
```

2) Then, to store values in the array:

```
k = Store(a, Int(0), int(5))
```

3) Finally, to retrieve the value:

```
print(simplify(k).arg(2))
```

I don't know if there is a better way to do that, I will appreciate also some feedback about that.

Now, the real question is: Can I append values in the array inside a for loop?
For example, is it possible to have something like :

```py
for i in range(10):
    Store(a, Int(i), Int(i*2))
```

The problem here is that to retrieve the saved values I need to save the "Store" operation inside a variable (like 'k' above).
I am pretty sure that should exist some way to do that..but it's too hard to find examples online !

Comment: I'm not familiar with PySMT; but I'd guess that you'd simply keep assigning to the same value, like this: `for i in range(10): a = Store(a, Int(i), Int(i*2))`. Try that.

Comment: Oh great, it works ! Thank you ! :D Do you also know how to select a single element in a given position ? Because the 'Select(array, index)' doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I think the confusion might arise from the difference between Store and Select as methods with side effects vs expressions.

When you do: `Store(a, Int(i), Int(i*2))` , you are building an expression in representing the result of performing the store. Therefore, as @alias suggests, you need to keep building on the same expression.

I would assume you might be running into a similar issue with `Select`. If you do `s = Select(a, Int(0))`, you are building an expression, not a value. If `a` is a has a value defined the index 0, you should be able to do `s.simplify()` and obtain the value.

In the example above, you should be able to replace your step 3) with simply that:

```
simplify(Select(k, Int(0))) # Int(5)
```

Edit: Full example following the discussion below

```py
from pysmt.shortcuts import Symbol, Store, Select, Int, get_model
from pysmt.typing import ArrayType, INT

a = Symbol("a", ArrayType(INT, INT))

for i in range(10):
    a = Store(a, Int(i), Int(i*2))

print(a.serialize())
# >>> a[0 := 0][1 := 2][2 := 4][3 := 6][4 := 8][5 := 10][6 := 12][7 := 14][8 := 16][9 := 18]

# x is the expression resulting from reading element 5
# Simplify does not manage to infer that the value should be 10
x = Select(a, Int(5))
print(x.simplify().serialize())
# >>> a[0 := 0][1 := 2][2 := 4][3 := 6][4 := 8][5 := 10][6 := 12][7 := 14][8 := 16][9 := 18][5]

# Ask the solver for a value:
# Note that we can only assert Boolean expressions, and not theory expressions, so we write a trivial expression a = a  
m = get_model(a.Equals(a))

# Evaluate the expression x within the model
print(m[x])
# >>> 10
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I tried to do some modifications, but I didn't reach the goal. If I write `k = Store(a, Int(i), int(i*2) )` inside a for loop, the value of `k`  will be the last in the loop (of course). So, if I write as you suggest `simplify(Select(k, Int(5)))` I obtain an output like `a[9 := 18][5]`. Instead, if I do as @alias suggested `a = Store(a, Int(i), int(i*2))` and try to print with the command `simplify(Select(a, Int(5)))` I obtain a string with all values, something like : `... [ ... := ...] [7 := 14][8 := 16][9 := 18][5]`. How can I store and retrieve values in array?

Comment: I think that just means that simplify wasn't able to reduce it any further than what it printed. It's still correct, just not what you expected to see. Just go ahead and use it in your queries and it'll work fine. Note that SMT-solving is not like "programming," you're merely constructing constraints that'll all be solved when you eventually call `check-sat`. (Or whatever the PySMT equivalent is.) The fact that `Simplify` didn't simplify as much as you wanted shouldn't be surprising since you can pass an arbitrary expression there and simplifier only does a few "cheap" things.

Comment: I created an issue following this discussion, thanks for bringing this up! https://github.com/pysmt/pysmt/issues/599